# Find third and n-th level domains in a network

Tags: networking, dns, internet, ip, domain

In [this page](https://www.utexas.edu/its/help/domain-name-hosting-and/848) an example about how domain naming works is provided.

The second-level domain is utexas.edu, then some third and fourth level domains are listed, like computerstore.utexas.edu and www.mccombs.utexas.edu.

Suppose that an entire network is connected to the internet, and each of his hosts have a *public* IP. Is it possible, given a certain n-level domain belonging to that network, to know all the (n-1)-level subdomains? I mean: is it possible to list them through publicly available informations (DNS queries...)?

For example, given site.com, I would like to know if it is possible to know all its third-level associated domains (like www.site.com), given that they belong to the same owner and that they all have a public address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS servers won't give you that information unless they give you transfer rights which they shouldn't unless it's your DNS server.  That would be available through `dig axfr domain.com @authoritativeDNSserver`.

I suppose if you had that access, you wouldn't ask that question.  This would likely mean that you can't get what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Should I run `dig axfr domain.com` against the authoritative DNS server? Or what else?

Comment: My post says that unless you are the DNS server's administrator, which is obviously not the case, you can not get that information.  DNS servers do not publicly share all their knowledge for security, privacy and performance reasons.

Comment: Ok, thanks. No, of course I'm not the DNS server's administrator. And are you sure that there's not another (public) way to gather those informations?

Comment: Yes I'm sure.  Some DNS servers could have lessened permissions but none would return the full record to everyone.  Lately, many have even stopped answering to ANY requests which simply give the first layer in one request.